# Possible to build a tolerance for the sleep hormone melatonin?

Tags: sleep-deprivation, sleep-aids, insomnia, drug-tolerance, melatonin

Good evening again, everybody!

As my backstory goes, I am an insomniac (why you get so many questions from me).

I am so fatigued, but no matter what, I just can't fall asleep...

I've tried Melatonin -- the natural sleep hormone -- before, and it worked for a while, but it lost its effectiveness quite quickly. I started upping the dosages to get that "sleepiness" effect, and then stopped because I didn't wanna do anything dangerous.

But I wasn't sure -- is it possible to build a tolerance to melatonin (if it's natural)? Or was it not working because I was more stressed than usual?

What is the highest safest dosage an adult of 150 lbs should take?

Thanks.